# Is there any method to prevent my Fontend ( html + css) design flow while using .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have done my project fontend design in html an css. But when I used this design in .NET Core .cshtml file its fontsize is getting increased in **Chrome** browser but in **Brave** it works fine. My whole design looks very bad.
Is there any method to prevent its fontsize as it designed already.

Comment: Remove any default css which will be injected by aspnet core

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove default css in a .cshtml file.You can try to remove css in `<head></head>` of `Shared/_Layout.cshtml`.

Or you can use the following code in a .cshtml file to specify current view's layout to null.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

If you want to specify current view's layout to null in all .cshtml files,try to use `Layout = null;` in `_ViewStart.cshtml`.